# Failed to import SwiperModule in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to import SwiperModule in my project module but it shows error. I tried each possible solutions but failed to solve it. I even uninstalled & reinstalled the swiper & also changed swiper version to 7, nevertheless it's not working.

in package.json,

```
"ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^8.0.2",
"swiper": "^7.4.1"
```

in tsconfig.json,

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "paths": {
            "swiper_angular": ["../node_modules/swiper/angular"]
    },
}
```

in app.module.ts,

```
import { SwiperModule } from "swiper/angular"
@NgModule({
  imports: {
    SwiperModule
  }
})
```

angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.24
Node: 14.15.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.11
```

error shows in terminal,

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:8:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

8     set zoom(val: boolean);
          ~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:9:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

9     get zoom(): boolean;
          ~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:12:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

12     get classNames(): string;
           ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:13:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

13     set classNames(val: string);
           ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:24:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

24     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SwiperSlideDirective, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper-slide.directive.d.ts:25:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration'.

25     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<SwiperSlideDirective, "ng-template[swiperSlide]", never, { "virtualIndex": "virtualIndex"; "class": "class"; "autoplayDelay": "data-swiper-autoplay"; "zoom": "zoom"; }, {}, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:120:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

120     set navigation(val: boolean | "" | NavigationOptions);
            ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:121:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

121     get navigation(): boolean | "" | NavigationOptions;
            ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:124:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

124     set pagination(val: boolean | "" | PaginationOptions);
            ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:125:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

125     get pagination(): boolean | "" | PaginationOptions;
            ~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:128:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

128     set scrollbar(val: boolean | "" | ScrollbarOptions);
            ~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:129:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

129     get scrollbar(): boolean | "" | ScrollbarOptions;
            ~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:132:9 - error[90m TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

132     set virtual(val: boolean | "" | VirtualOptions);
            ~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:133:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

133     get virtual(): boolean | "" | VirtualOptions;
            ~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:135:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

135     set index(index: number);
            ~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:136:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

136     set config(val: SwiperOptions);
            ~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:216:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

216     set prevElRef(el: ElementRef);
            ~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:218:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

218     set nextElRef(el: ElementRef);
            ~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:220:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

220     set scrollbarElRef(el: ElementRef);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:222:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

222     set paginationElRef(el: ElementRef);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:230:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

230     get activeSlides(): Observable<SwiperSlideDirective[]>;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:231:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

231     get zoomContainerClass(): string;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:239:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

239     get isSwiperActive(): boolean;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:254:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

254     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SwiperComponent, never>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.component.d.ts:255:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

255     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<SwiperComponent, "swiper, [swiper]", never, { "enabled": "enabled"; "on": "on"; "direction": "direction"; "touchEventsTarget": "touchEventsTarget"; "initialSlide": "initialSlide"; "speed": "speed"; "cssMode": "cssMode"; "updateOnWindowResize": "updateOnWindowResize"; "resizeObserver": "resizeObserver"; "nested": "nested"; "focusableElements": "focusableElements"; "width": "width"; "height": "height"; "preventInteractionOnTransition": "preventInteractionOnTransition"; "userAgent": "userAgent"; "url": "url"; "edgeSwipeDetection": "edgeSwipeDetection"; "edgeSwipeThreshold": "edgeSwipeThreshold"; "freeMode": "freeMode"; "autoHeight": "autoHeight"; "setWrapperSize": "setWrapperSize"; "virtualTranslate": "virtualTranslate"; "effect": "effect"; "breakpoints": "breakpoints"; "spaceBetween": "spaceBetween"; "slidesPerView": "slidesPerView"; "grid": "grid"; "slidesPerGroup": "slidesPerGroup"; "slidesPerGroupSkip": "slidesPerGroupSkip"; "centeredSlides": "centeredSlides"; "centeredSlidesBounds": "centeredSlidesBounds"; "slidesOffsetBefore": "slidesOffsetBefore"; "slidesOffsetAfter": "slidesOffsetAfter"; "normalizeSlideIndex": "normalizeSlideIndex"; "centerInsufficientSlides": "centerInsufficientSlides"; "watchOverflow": "watchOverflow"; "roundLengths": "roundLengths"; "touchRatio": "touchRatio"; "touchAngle": "touchAngle"; "simulateTouch": "simulateTouch"; "shortSwipes": "shortSwipes"; "longSwipes": "longSwipes"; "longSwipesRatio": "longSwipesRatio"; "longSwipesMs": "longSwipesMs"; "followFinger": "followFinger"; "allowTouchMove": "allowTouchMove"; "threshold": "threshold"; "touchMoveStopPropagation": "touchMoveStopPropagation"; "touchStartPreventDefault": "touchStartPreventDefault"; "touchStartForcePreventDefault": "touchStartForcePreventDefault"; "touchReleaseOnEdges": "touchReleaseOnEdges"; "uniqueNavElements": "uniqueNavElements"; "resistance": "resistance"; "resistanceRatio": "resistanceRatio"; "watchSlidesProgress": "watchSlidesProgress"; "grabCursor": "grabCursor"; "preventClicks": "preventClicks"; "preventClicksPropagation": "preventClicksPropagation"; "slideToClickedSlide": "slideToClickedSlide"; "preloadImages": "preloadImages"; "updateOnImagesReady": "updateOnImagesReady"; "loop": "loop"; "loopAdditionalSlides": "loopAdditionalSlides"; "loopedSlides": "loopedSlides"; "loopFillGroupWithBlank": "loopFillGroupWithBlank"; "loopPreventsSlide": "loopPreventsSlide"; "rewind": "rewind"; "allowSlidePrev": "allowSlidePrev"; "allowSlideNext": "allowSlideNext"; "swipeHandler": "swipeHandler"; "noSwiping": "noSwiping"; "noSwipingClass": "noSwipingClass"; "noSwipingSelector": "noSwipingSelector"; "passiveListeners": "passiveListeners"; "containerModifierClass": "containerModifierClass"; "slideClass": "slideClass"; "slideBlankClass": "slideBlankClass"; "slideActiveClass": "slideActiveClass"; "slideDuplicateActiveClass": "slideDuplicateActiveClass"; "slideVisibleClass": "slideVisibleClass"; "slideDuplicateClass": "slideDuplicateClass"; "slideNextClass": "slideNextClass"; "slideDuplicateNextClass": "slideDuplicateNextClass"; "slidePrevClass": "slidePrevClass"; "slideDuplicatePrevClass": "slideDuplicatePrevClass"; "wrapperClass": "wrapperClass"; "runCallbacksOnInit": "runCallbacksOnInit"; "observeParents": "observeParents"; "observeSlideChildren": "observeSlideChildren"; "a11y": "a11y"; "autoplay": "autoplay"; "controller": "controller"; "coverflowEffect": "coverflowEffect"; "cubeEffect": "cubeEffect"; "fadeEffect": "fadeEffect"; "flipEffect": "flipEffect"; "creativeEffect": "creativeEffect"; "cardsEffect": "cardsEffect"; "hashNavigation": "hashNavigation"; "history": "history"; "keyboard": "keyboard"; "lazy": "lazy"; "mousewheel": "mousewheel"; "parallax": "parallax"; "thumbs": "thumbs"; "zoom": "zoom"; "class": "class"; "id": "id"; "navigation": "navigation"; "pagination": "pagination"; "scrollbar": "scrollbar"; "virtual": "virtual"; "index": "index"; "config": "config"; }, { "s__beforeBreakpoint": "_beforeBreakpoint"; "s__containerClasses": "_containerClasses"; "s__slideClass": "_slideClass"; "s__swiper": "_swiper"; "s_activeIndexChange": "activeIndexChange"; "s_afterInit": "afterInit"; "s_autoplay": "autoplay"; "s_autoplayStart": "autoplayStart"; "s_autoplayStop": "autoplayStop"; "s_beforeDestroy": "beforeDestroy"; "s_beforeInit": "beforeInit"; "s_beforeLoopFix": "beforeLoopFix"; "s_beforeResize": "beforeResize"; "s_beforeSlideChangeStart": "beforeSlideChangeStart"; "s_beforeTransitionStart": "beforeTransitionStart"; "s_breakpoint": "breakpoint"; "s_changeDirection": "changeDirection"; "s_click": "click"; "s_doubleTap": "doubleTap"; "s_doubleClick": "doubleClick"; "s_destroy": "destroy"; "s_fromEdge": "fromEdge"; "s_hashChange": "hashChange"; "s_hashSet": "hashSet"; "s_imagesReady": "imagesReady"; "s_init": "init"; "s_keyPress": "keyPress"; "s_lazyImageLoad": "lazyImageLoad"; "s_lazyImageReady": "lazyImageReady"; "s_loopFix": "loopFix"; "s_momentumBounce": "momentumBounce"; "s_navigationHide": "navigationHide"; "s_navigationShow": "navigationShow"; "s_observerUpdate": "observerUpdate"; "s_orientationchange": "orientationchange"; "s_paginationHide": "paginationHide"; "s_paginationRender": "paginationRender"; "s_paginationShow": "paginationShow"; "s_paginationUpdate": "paginationUpdate"; "s_progress": "progress"; "s_reachBeginning": "reachBeginning"; "s_reachEnd": "reachEnd"; "s_realIndexChange": "realIndexChange"; "s_resize": "resize"; "s_scroll": "scroll"; "s_scrollbarDragEnd": "scrollbarDragEnd"; "s_scrollbarDragMove": "scrollbarDragMove"; "s_scrollbarDragStart": "scrollbarDragStart"; "s_setTransition": "setTransition"; "s_setTranslate": "setTranslate"; "s_slideChange": "slideChange"; "s_slideChangeTransitionEnd": "slideChangeTransitionEnd"; "s_slideChangeTransitionStart": "slideChangeTransitionStart"; "s_slideNextTransitionEnd": "slideNextTransitionEnd"; "s_slideNextTransitionStart": "slideNextTransitionStart"; "s_slidePrevTransitionEnd": "slidePrevTransitionEnd"; "s_slidePrevTransitionStart": "slidePrevTransitionStart"; "s_slideResetTransitionStart": "slideResetTransitionStart"; "s_slideResetTransitionEnd": "slideResetTransitionEnd"; "s_sliderMove": "sliderMove"; "s_sliderFirstMove": "sliderFirstMove"; "s_slidesLengthChange": "slidesLengthChange"; "s_slidesGridLengthChange": "slidesGridLengthChange"; "s_snapGridLengthChange": "snapGridLengthChange"; "s_snapIndexChange": "snapIndexChange"; "s_tap": "tap"; "s_toEdge": "toEdge"; "s_touchEnd": "touchEnd"; "s_touchMove": "touchMove"; "s_touchMoveOpposite": "touchMoveOpposite"; "s_touchStart": "touchStart"; "s_transitionEnd": "transitionEnd"; "s_transitionStart": "transitionStart"; "s_update": "update"; "s_zoomChange": "zoomChange"; "s_lock": "lock"; "s_unlock": "unlock"; "s_swiper": "swiper"; "indexChange": "indexChange"; }, ["slidesEl"], ["[slot=container-start]", "[slot=wrapper-start]", "[slot=wrapper-end]", "[slot=container-end]"]>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.module.d.ts:6:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SwiperModule, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.module.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

7     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<SwiperModule, [typeof i1.SwiperComponent, typeof i2.SwiperSlideDirective], [typeof i3.CommonModule], [typeof i1.SwiperComponent, typeof i2.SwiperSlideDirective]>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/swiper/angular/angular/src/swiper.module.d.ts:8:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

8     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<SwiperModule>;
```

could anyone tell me where's the problem? Thanks